# Asp.net LoginView Rolegroups don't show elements

Tags: asp.net, webforms, roles, user-roles, loginview

I'm using rolegroups at my Site.Master masterpage with Web Forms template. When I log in with some admin user, the first page shows the admin role content fine, but when I refresh the page or goes to other page, the elements in Rolegroups disappear. Only the LoggedInTemplate are showed. Someone knows why this are happening?? I don't find any situation like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved setting **cacheRolesInCookie="false"** in RoleManager at Web.config. Thanks.